# Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'classifiedsCtrl' is not registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to angular. Had it running fine with no controller then added ng-controller directive to html markup and broke interpolation. Using Angular 1.6. What am I missing?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ngClassifieds</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="ngClassifieds" ng-controller="classifiedsCtrl">

    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="components/classifieds.ctr.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module("ngClassifieds", []);
```

**classifieds.ctr.js**

```
(function() {
    "use strict"

    angular
        .module("ngClassifieds")
        .controller("classifiedsCtrl", function($scope) {

            $scope.name = "George Washington";
        });
    })();
```

Comment: paths are correct?

Comment: may be <script src="scripts/components/classifieds.ctr.js"></script>..check your path of ctrl file

Comment: checked file path and was not the issue. Thanks though

Comment: @user3911617 seems like problem with the paths. i just create a plnker and in works fine https://plnkr.co/edit/b7SjRN5PMeFT2EmreTUj?p=preview

Answer (score -2):

It is like you are declaring the app twice, try this :

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module("ngClassifieds", []);
```

classifieds.ctr.js

```
myApp.controller("classifiedsCtrl", function($scope) {
      $scope.name = "George Washington";
   });
```

Comment: No...`angular.module("ngClassifieds")` is a getter, not a setter, when no second argument is present and your approach requires exposing a global variable which is not needed. See [John Papa Angular Style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#iife)